# How put a image with auto size inside of a column using React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a row with two-column and want to put an image in one of the columns with full size.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mapping, light as lightTheme } from '@eva-design/eva';
import { View, ImageBackground, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ApplicationProvider, Layout } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { Input, InputProps } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { Text, Button } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

const App = () => (
    <ApplicationProvider
        mapping={mapping}
        theme={lightTheme}>
        <View style={styles.box}>
            <View style={{width: '50%', backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
                <Image
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={require('../ProjectName/assets/image.jpg')}
                style={styles.canvas} />
            </View>
            <View style={{width: '50%', backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                <Input />
                <Button />
            </View>
        </View>
    </ApplicationProvider>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    box: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: 'auto',
        maxHeight: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    canvas: {
        width: '100%',
    },
});

export default App;
```

Structure:

- ApplicationProvider
- - View
- - - View
- - - - Image
- - - View
- - - - Input
- - - - Button

My image is out of the column and box
[image: React native demo, app, run]!

Please guide me to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Text,
    View,
    ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1/3, height: 100, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1/2, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                        <Image style={{flex: 1, width: '100%', height: 'auto'}} source={require('./assets/image.png')}/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1/2, backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```